# Maven cyclic dependency error with EJBs acting as server as ejb client too

Tags: java, maven, ejb, wildfly, circular-dependency

I created two projects with the same structure that will be packaged to ear and deployed using WildFly 29 Domain.
A project contains an EJB module and a WEB module

Let them be A and B

I have done some research and I followed the [quickstart-ejb-multi-server](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/main/ejb-multi-server/README.adoc#install_the_quickstart_parent_artifact_in_maven) and A and B hase the same structure in it.
I am already able to call A from B, but when I tried to call B from A, I got a problem with the **maven cyclic dependency**, because **A's EJB must be in B's pom.xml dependencies and the same as B's EJB must be in A's pom.xml dependencies**

The main pom.xml contains:

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

The A or B' pom.xml contains:

```
<modules>
    <module>ejb</module>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>ear</module>
</modules>
```

And  B's EJB pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>A-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb-client</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.0.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.2.0.Final</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>19.8.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am able to call A from B and now I can' t do the inverse
I have already searched how to solve the cyclic dependency, but I didn't find a solution for EJB
What should I do ?

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? You should be able to do this with the deployment in WildFly, but you can't do it in a Maven build.

Comment: I mean I want that the EJB act as a server as a client too, but to be able to do that each of them need the dependency of the other

Answer (score 0):

You can't have circular dependencies like that in build tools as it has to build one first. However, it can't build one without the other. You may want to consider handling this differently. Either put the common types into their own library or combine the two into a single library.